# clear cache on current users' device in migrating from webpack 3 to 4

Tags: reactjs, webpack, service-worker

I have a reactjs PWA based on webpack and [offline-plugin](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin). currently I have a working application based on Webpack 3. I updated my webpack version to 4 and now I want to release my new version. but I have a big issue here. when I upgrade my PWA to webpack 4 in a device which old version is cached, service worker does not detect changes and would not update application.
could anybody help me on this issue.

this is my updating peace of code, which works great on webpack 3 but not on migration from webpack 3 to 4:

```
const runtime = require('offline-plugin/runtime');

runtime.install({
onUpdating: () => {
    console.log('SW Event:', 'onUpdating');
},
onUpdateReady: () => {
    console.log('SW Event:', 'onUpdateReady');
    runtime.applyUpdate();
},
onUpdated: () => {
    console.log('SW Event:', 'onUpdated');
    window.location.reload();
},
onUpdateFailed: () => {
    console.log('SW Event:', 'onUpdateFailed');
}
});
```

Comment: It's better to add version to your file with this way you don't need to consider about the cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself finally found the solution. the problem was that, my new chunk names was not exactly same as previous version. so in upgrading webpack, your new service worker name and new chunk names should be exactly same as previous version.